# Given that $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is continuous and not surjective then $f(S^1)$ is homeomorphic to and interval $I$

Tags: general-topology, circles, homotopy-theory

I have been looking at circle functions and wanted to prove that if $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is not surjective then it is degree zero.

Furthermore, I have dismissed using the extension of the circle Theorem if we can extend the domain to a disk and decided to use properties of the image.

So I am proving,
**Given that $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is continuous and not surjective then $f(S^1)$ is homeomorphic to and interval $I$.**

If any other methods, please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $S^1\setminus\{\text{point}\}\cong\Bbb R$.  And the continuous image of a connected set is connected.  Not only that, the image is compact, as well: continuity preserves compactness.

Comment: Furthermore, as it is a compact and connected suubset of a contractible space. It is is then contractible. So proof should follow